# How to join an image to text

Tags: html

I need a special symbol that is unavailable so I'm using an image the same size as the text in its place. The problem is, when I reach the end of a line, it draws the image and wraps the text to the next line which looks wrong.
I can't force a line break becuase it would then look wrong on screens with different resolutions. Is there a way to join the text to the image so that if it needs to wrap, it will wrap the image along with the text?

Comment: Can you post screenshot of desired behaviour? Hard to figure it out.

Comment: Which symbol do you need? Its highly likely that its available in one of the Unicode sets.

Comment: It is a Webdings symbols that is supported by only two of the five major browsers. IE and Safari I think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap the word in a `<span>` tag, and use `white-space:nowrap;` on the span.

```
<p>This is text with a
    <span class="word">wor<img src="symbol.gif">d</span>
    with a symbol in it.
</p>
```

CSS

```
.word {
    white-space:nowrap;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might do best to make an image of the entire set of characters that make a "word". That way if it wraps, it stays together.

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping the word containing the image+text in a `<pre>` or a `<span>` tag